# Does C# automatically "dispose" IDisposable objects when they fall out of scope?

Tags: c#, dispose

I am writing an ASP.NET Web API. As part of this, I have a class that I found out, during testing, needs to implement `IDisposable` to ensure managed resources are freed.

So, I implemented `IDisposable` in my class, and put the code necessary to free the resources in the `Dispose()` method.

There are many places in my code (hundreds) where I instantiate this object, and in the same line call a method on the new instance. I only need the instance to call the single method.

Here's an example:

```
// MyObject, a class that needs to be disposed of.
public class MyObject : IDisposable
{
    private AnObjectThatMustBeDisposed localObject;

    public MyObject() 
    {
        localObject = SomeLibrary.SomeProject.AnObjectThatMustBeDisposed.Create();
    }

    public void doOperationOne()
    {
        localObject.DoSomething(1);
    }

    public string getOperationTwo()
    {
        return localObject.DoSomething(2);
    }

    public string getOperationThree()
    {
        return localObject.DoSomething(3);
    }

    public bool getOperationFour(string input)
    {
        return localObject.DoSomethingSpecial(4,input.ToLower());
    }

    ...

    public void getOperationOneHundred(DateTime input)
    {
        localObject.DoSomethingElse(100,input);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        localObject.CloseResources();
        localObject.FreeUpMemory();
        localObject.Close();
        localObject.Dispose();
    }
}

// A class that makes use of MyObject
public class MyLibraryThatUsesMyObject
{
    public void Method1()
    {
        new MyObject().doOperationOne();
    }
    public string Method2()
    {
        return new MyObject().getOperationTwo();
    }
    public int Method3()
    {
        return new MyObject().getOperationThree();
    }
    public bool Method4(string testString)
    {
        if (testString.Length > 6)
        {
            if (new MyObject().getOperationFour(testString)) return true;
            else return false;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    ...

    public void Method100()
    {
        new MyObject().doOperationOneHundred(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

My question is: Does .NET automatically `Dispose()` objects when they fall out of scope? Or, do I actually have to do this...

```
public void Method1() 
{
    using (MyObject o = new MyObject())
    {
        o.DoOperationOne();
    }
}
```

...to each method? It wouldn't be hard if I had two or three methods, but if I have tons of methods, this refactoring could take quite a while.

I am not sure how ASP.NET handles requests as they complete - i.e. does the framework give code time to `Dispose()` things, or does it "cut off" execution as soon as the `return` is called, not letting things dispose?

The fact that, without implementing `IDisposable` myself, things inside the `MyObject` class are failing due to unreleased resources causing leaks, it feels like .NET does *not* automatically `Dispose` things. So, if that's the case, can I do something so I don't have to refactor hundreds of methods?

---

**EDIT**: I tried simply implementing `IDisposable`, but my unit test was still able to produce a resource leak. So it would appear that my suspicion that .NET is not automatically disposing is correct. So now my question becomes - how can I force disposing without having to refactor hundreds of methods?

Comment: Actually `Dispose` if for release **unmanaged** resources, not **managed**. That's why you have to call it manually.

Comment: @kirill no that's not true. Every class that implements `IDisposable` is a managed object and will still need to be released. Maybe its using unmanaged code inside but that's upto the class.

Comment: @CodingYoshi --> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk I have read many articles and that is bad advice from MS. I don't think you would even agree with that advice. For example the first line in the article says "You implement a Dispose method to release unmanaged resources used by your application.". So if I am using `StreamReader` or `SqlConnection` (managed resources) I do not need to implement `IDisposable`? Clearly that is not true. What if I have them as fields of my class. Not sure why they would says that...

Comment: `IDisposable` by itself is no use, you should also use the `using(...)` statement.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, `SqlConnection` uses **unmanaged** resources internally (DB connection). Strictly speaking, you should implement `IDisposable` for any class which uses **unmanaged** resources, so any consumer of your class can correctly release (dispose) any **unmanaged** resources used by your class. After all, `IDisposable` is just an interface (contract) between consumer and class provider, nothing more.

Comment: Correct and i said that in my original comment: `Maybe its using unmanaged code inside but that's upto the class`

Comment: Should the resource be disposed of when the method exits, or should the resource stick around until the entire object goes out of scope and be disposed of at that point? Also, you should carefully debug your unit test to make certain that your dispose method is cleaning everything up properly. I have implemented IDisposable many times and it has always worked quite well for me.

Answer (score 7):

Dispose is not automatically called. If you don't call `.Dispose()` (either explicitly or via a `using` statement) the method will never be called.

The only caveat is methods that are implemented with the pattern

```
public void Dispose()
{
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    Dispose(true);
}

~MyClass()
{
    Dispose(false);
}

bool _isDisposed = false;
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposeing)
{
    if(_isDisposed)
        return;

    _isDisposed = true;

    if(disposing)
    {
        //Disposed managed code here
    }

    //Dispose unmanaged code only here.
}
```

Will have `Dispose(false)` called on it when the object is finalized, but you are not allowed to dispose (or even access) managed objects (i.e: other stuff that implements `.Dispose()`) when `disposing` is `false`.

You will need to refactor your code if you want your resources disposed correctly.

There is a really, *really*, good article written by Stephen Cleary "[IDisposable: What Your Mother Never Told You About Resource Deallocation](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29534/IDisposable-What-Your-Mother-Never-Told-You-About)" that does a very good job explaining how Dispose works and how to correctly write your own disposeable objects (for example, that caveat pattern I mentioned above is recommended by Microsoft but is actually a very bad pattern to do. Classes should only either hold only managed resources or derive from `SafeHandle` and only hold a unmanaged resource and possibly other `SafeHandles`. You should never have a class that holds both managed and unmanaged resources nor a single class that holds multiple unmanaged resources)

Comment: "You should never have a class that holds both managed and unmanaged resources)"--first time I am hearing this. Any suggestions for a more elaborate reading?

Comment: @CodingYoshi that advice is from the article I linked to, specifically the section titled "Solving IDisposable's Difficulties - Minimize Use Cases of IDisposable by Utilizing the Disposable Design Principle"

Answer (score 3):

> I am not sure how ASP.NET handles requests as they complete - i.e. does the framework give code time to Dispose() things, or does it "cut off" execution as soon as the return is called, not letting things dispose?

My answer will try to answer the specific question above since you have gotten answers to your other question.

In the MVC framework there is a class that creates controllers. It is named `DefaultControllerFactory` and it has this method:

```
public virtual void ReleaseController(IController controller)
{
    IDisposable disposable = controller as IDisposable;
    if (disposable != null)
    {
        disposable.Dispose();
    }
```

}

Please note the parameter the above method takes: `IController`. So it passes your controller class (since all controllers implement that interface by deriving the `BaseController`) and if your controller implements `IDisposable`, it will cast it and then call `Dispose()` on it. So it gives you a chance to do whatever cleanup you need to do.

If you have rolled your own factory and you are not using the `DefaultControllerFactory` then make sure you are doing the same thing and calling the `Dispose` on the controllers.

I got the above source code from [MVC's Source Code](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultControllerFactory.cs).

Comment: I suspected this behavior was likely the case, and thank you for posting this specific content.

Answer (score 0):

No, the CLR will *never* call Dispose on your object when it goes out of scope. It will, however, call the class destructor (which must be explicitly overridden).

**Note: The example that follows is not intended to demonstrate what should be done in production code. The practice recommended by Microsoft can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx).**

Consider the following class:

```
public class MyDisposable : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Disposing this disposable instance.");
    }

    // Note: This is not the right way to implement the dispose pattern. See
    // the MSDN docs on the recommended pattern.
    ~MyDisposable()
    {
        Dispose();
    }
}
```

Now, write this method that uses it, and set a break point on the `MyDispoable.Dispose` method.

```
private static void UseDisposable()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter");
    var disposable = new MyDisposable();
    Console.WriteLine("Exit");
}
```

What you will see is that, when leaving this scope, not only is the `Dispose` on `MyDisposable` not called, but neither is the finalizer. This means that the locals you created in your method are not cleaned up at the end of the method, even though they are local to the method (not returned to the caller, or assigned to any other object).

The way that I try to manage disposable resources in my own code is by not using them as class members, and put all of them inside of `using` blocks. Keep in mind that a using is only syntax sugar for `try {...} finally {...}`, though.

Now, I think your question is more about ASP.NET than the CLR. I am not sure of what ASP.NET does to handle disposable resources. If you are using the resource inside of a Controller, then have a go at implementing IDisposable, and using a break point to see if it gets called after your method completes. That's a scenario that I'm not as sure about, but it seems reasonable that it may work that way.

**Edit:** See the answer from @CodingYoshi regarding ASP.NET controller disposal. It turns out that MVC will deterministically call dispose, so some of your refactoring may be slightly more simple.

Comment: There are very strict limitatinos on what you can do in a destructor method, just blanket calling `Dispose()` in it is a very unsafe thing to recommend.

Comment: Of course. This was meant only for demonstration - not for a real implementation. The point is to show that in C#, resources aren't intrinsically disposed/collected upon changing scopes.